# Pandas Groupby Head by Percentage of Row Counts

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
state    city             score
CA       San Francisco    80
CA       San Francisco    90
...
NC       Raleigh          44
NY       New York City    22
```

I want to do a groupby.head(), but instead of an integer value, I want to select the top 80%, *sorted by Score*, of each state-city combo.

So if CA, San Francisco has 100 rows, and NC, Raleigh has 20 rows, the final dataframe would have the top 80 score rows for CA, San Francisco, and the top 16 score rows for NC, Raleigh.

So the final result code might look something like:

```
df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).groupby(['State', 'City']).head(80%)
```

Thanks!

Comment: [pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html)?

Comment: @It_is_Chris This is close, but it only returns a % of rows selected randomly, and I need the % to be sorted by the score column.

Realized I didn't clarify this in my original post so I will edit now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# sample data
s = """state,city,score
CA,San Francisco,80
CA,San Francisco,90
CA,San Francisco,30
CA,San Francisco,10
CA,San Francisco,70
CA,San Francisco,60
CA,San Francisco,50
CA,San Francisco,40
NC,Raleigh,44
NC,Raleigh,54
NC,Raleigh,64
NC,Raleigh,14
NY,New York City,22
NY,New York City,12
NY,New York City,32
NY,New York City,42
NY,New York City,52"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

sample = .8 # 80% 
# sort the values and create a groupby object
g = df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).groupby(['state', 'city']) 
# use list comprehension to iterate over each group
# for each group, calculate what 80% is
# in other words, the length of each group multiplied by .8
# you then use int to round down to the whole number
new_df = pd.concat([data.head(int(len(data)*sample)) for _,data in g])

   state           city  score
1     CA  San Francisco     90
0     CA  San Francisco     80
4     CA  San Francisco     70
5     CA  San Francisco     60
6     CA  San Francisco     50
7     CA  San Francisco     40
10    NC        Raleigh     64
9     NC        Raleigh     54
8     NC        Raleigh     44
16    NY  New York City     52
15    NY  New York City     42
14    NY  New York City     32
12    NY  New York City     22
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) and compute the number of selected rows per group based on its length, i.e. `0.8 * len(group)`

```
res = (
    df.groupby(['State', 'City'], group_keys=False)
      .apply(lambda g: g.nlargest(int(0.8*len(g)), "Score"))
)
```